# SKSpriteNode from image touch detection

Tags: ios, touch, sprite-kit, shapes

I have some SKSpriteNode from image like this :

[image]

When I try to detect touch like this :

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:self];
    SKNode *node = [self nodeAtPoint:location];
    if ([node.name isEqualToString:@"shape"]) {
        NSLog(@"TOUCH DETECT");
    }
}
```

it detect touch even if I touch outside blue shape in the corners. It take square shape for touch detection. How to get around it ? I want to detect touch only inside blu shape.

Marko

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event 
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:self];
    SKNode *node = [self nodeAtPoint:location];
    if ([node.name isEqualToString:@"shapeMask"]) {
        //Whatever you want.
    }
}
-(void)blueShape{
    SKSpriteNode *blueShape = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"blueShape"];
    blueShape.position = yourPosition;
    blueShape.name = @"blueShape";
    [self addChild:blueShape];

    SKShapeNode *shapeMask = [SKShapeNode node];
    shapeMask.name = @"shapeMask";
    CGFloat offsetX = blueShape.frame.size.width * blueShape.anchorPoint.x;
    CGFloat offsetY = blueShape.frame.size.height * blueShape.anchorPoint.y;

    CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();

    CGPathMoveToPoint(path, NULL, 0 - offsetX, 137 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 80 - offsetX, 1 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 239 - offsetX, 2 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 318 - offsetX, 139 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 238 - offsetX, 275 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 80 - offsetX, 274 - offsetY);
    //Values may not be accurate. You can set yourself with shape tool.
    CGPathCloseSubpath(path);

    [shapeMask setPath:path];
    [blueShape addChild:shapeMask];
}
```

Comment: I have this set, (I edit question) but it still detect touches in corners where blue shapes are not visible.

Comment: If your image is png. It can detect already blue shape. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics

Comment: I have png image. You can try it (it is paste in question). It has transparent backgroung

Comment: Use this method. I tested it works with your image. By the way, You can use this tool for shape nodes http://dazchong.com/spritekit/